# Sqlite sorting using regex

Tags: java, android, regex, sqlite, sorting

Sqlite sorting using regex

I have rows in an sqlite db text field (codes) with values like:

```
M1 
M2/4527
M101
1
2/5
3/1003
101
102
```

I wish to sort codes with all the rows that start with a number first followed by all the codes that start with a letter A through Z.

This is the nearest I've got

```
rawdata = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY CASE WHEN " + codes + " GLOB '*^[0-9]*' THEN CAST(" + codes + " AS INTEGER) ELSE CAST(" + codes + " AS TEXT) END, " + codes + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC", null);
```

Which gives me this:

```
1
101
102
2/5
3/1003
M1
M101
M2/4527
```

The sort order I'm trying to achieve is:

```
1
2/5
3/1003
101
102
M1
M2/4527
M101
```

The codes that contain a slash can, if easier, have the slash and characters after ignored, as long as the character preceding the slash are sorted as per my requirement. So 2/5 would be 2 and 3/1003 would be 3.

Comment: Can't you just retrieve the values and sort them with Java using your own `Comparator`?

Comment: I will if it turns out this is not possible while populating the cursor. Would make my code much more simple if I could do it with the db.query though.

Comment: not sure about simpler with the SQL query. Imagine having a change in the order/comparison later on, and debugging/fixing that query... It's probably non-trivial with `Comparator` either, but at least way easier to debug!

Comment: At the entries beginning with a letter, can you assume they will always begin with just one letter? At the numeric entries, is there a limit value expected?

Comment: Yes the codes that begin with a letter, will always be one letter. The codes that are just numbers, can be 1 to 5 digits long. However those that have a / could be longer as they are in fact two codes with a separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the rows with a letter correctly, you have to extract that number from the string.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TableName
ORDER BY CASE WHEN codes GLOB '[0-9]*'      THEN 0
              WHEN codes GLOB '[A-Z][0-9]*' THEN substr(codes, 1, 1)
              ELSE                               codes
         END,
         CASE WHEN codes GLOB '[0-9]*'      THEN CAST(codes            AS INT)
              WHEN codes GLOB '[A-Z][0-9]*' THEN CAST(substr(codes, 2) AS INT)
              ELSE                               codes
         END
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be the regex to catch any letter, not just M
GLOB 'M[0-9]*'

Comment: Cool, nearly there... however sort on codes beginning with letters now goes: M01, P2, M02, P3, M03 etc. Do you think there is a way so it will also sort first on first letter then on numbers? Thanks for you help.

Comment: BTW What does + 1000000 represent? Number of characters, number of rows?

Comment: Fixed - Thanks CL, really appreciate your help on this! Now I know I can use substr as part of query that will help with other stuff too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with GLOB regex, changed to

```
GLOB '[0-9]*'
```

got things working better but codes that start with a letter followed by numbers are not sorting numerically (the way I want) after the letter.

Comment: True, but a step in the right direction for the codes not starting with a letter and those that have /. Hopefully someone may have some more insight to get those sorting as well.